# Cocos2d crash on iOS9 simulator

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios9

```
2015-10-26 21:30:19.093 QP[4494:55623]   39: 
OpenGL error GL_INVALID_VALUE detected at -[CCGraphicsBufferGLUnsynchronized setup] 121
2015-10-26 21:30:19.096 QP[4494:55623] *** Assertion failure in -[CCRenderStateGL initWithBlendMode:shader:shaderUniforms:copyUniforms:], /Users/quantum/code/fuck/quantumpilot/qp/Source/libs/cocos2d-iphone/cocos2d/CCRendererBasicTypes.m:313
2015-10-26 21:30:19.139 QP[4494:55623] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'CCRenderState: Shader is nil'
```

Why is this happening? Works fine on my 8.4.1 device. Will test on 9.1 device.

EDIT

From http://forum.cocos2d-objc.org/t/xcode-7-ios9-beta/17346/20

`added to static NSString *CCShaderHeader in CCShader.m
@"#ifdef GL_ES\n"
@"#ifdef GL_OES_standard_derivatives\n"
@"#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable\n"
@"#endif\n"
@"#endif\n"
removed from CCDrawNode.m
@"#ifdef GL_ES\n"
@"#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable\n"
@"#endif\n"
@"\n"`

fixes it. Arcane.